# Applying _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS only to a fragment of code

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-warnings

Is there a way to apply _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS only to s fragment of code?  I tried the obvious

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
// some code here
#undef _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

It seems it doesn't work.

Comment: The #define only has an affect at #include time, it alters the function prototypes.  Moving it into a separate source file is the best way to ensure it gnaws your conscience.

Answer (score 1):

The `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` flag is applied to the declarations of the relevant functions when they're included in your source code. You can't really turn them on or off on a per-call basis, it's an all-or-nothing setting. That's why the `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` directive must come before the `#include` directives that include the relevant function declarations.

As an alternative, you can bracket your calls with `#pragma warning` directives to turn off that specific warning:

```cpp
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
    printf("Look Ma, no warnings!\n");
    printf("This is awesome!\n");
#pragma warning(pop)

// or for just one call,
#pragma warning(suppress:4996)
    printf("We'll look the other way just this once.\n");
```